# Alternative to TableGateway for Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, tablegateway

I'm using **Zend framework 2** to create web pages.

Through **TableGateway** I'm accessing my **PostgreSQL** **DB**.

Is there any alternative to **TableGateway** that can be used effectively in **Zend framework 2**, with easy-to-use documentation and stuff?

I'm trying to get away from **Doctrine 2** (*unless you could convince me otherwise*).

*Any help would be appretiated.*

Comment: How about a Nosql solution like mongo? Or does it have to be postgre? If not https://github.com/phly/PhlyMongo could be an alternative.

Comment: More information is needed as to why you're "trying to get away from Doctrine" as it could change my answer. Also I'm confused by "easy to use documentation and stuff". Zend has some of the best (it's not *perfect*) documentation for a framework. Have you researched into the TableGateway pattern in a more generic way? It would defiantly help you understand the ZF specific implementation and perhaps make the documentation clearer.

Comment: @AlexP yes I know about tablegateway that it is easy to use, but the Project requirement tells me to do so . . . isn't doctrine so heavy and complicated to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, I used 3 ways to handle data access.

- TableGateway patter is ok but it's not easy to maintain for larger applications.
- Another commonly used pattern is the data mapper pattern, for this you can use AbstractDbMapper and hydrator for mapping. [AbstracDbMapper Link](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcBase/blob/master/src/ZfcBase/Mapper/AbstractDbMapper.php)
- Entity pattern, like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/)

I finally decided to use doctrine basically cause is very easy to maintain and you can save some hours of code, but if you don't want to use doctrine i think that Data Mapper Pattern is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

What is really confusing? If you are using Zend MVC, Then Service Manager/Locator is using every where and that is way to define TableGateway/DB Models too. Model's code still good and understanding. I don't understand where is really confusing.

One change I can suggest the original ZF 2.0 style simpler getServiceConfig which is working for me till now.

```
'Album\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm) {
    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
    $table = new Model\AlbumTable($dbAdapter);
    return $table;
},
```

Instead of

```
'Album\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm) {
     $tableGateway = $sm->get('AlbumTableGateway');
     $table = new AlbumTable($tableGateway);
     return $table;
 },
 'AlbumTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
     $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
     $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
     $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Album());
     return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
 },
```

I did not faced any problem by using previous one but can't say if others faced  ?

Comment: Its already too late I have decided to change. looking for an alternative. so this will not do.

Comment: TableGateway pattern is simple but sure is not the best pattern for larger applications. I tried to find another pattern examples like mapper classes with AbstractDbMapper https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcBase/blob/master/src/ZfcBase/Mapper/AbstractDbMapper.php , well i finally decided to use doctrine2.